# Workbox: cannot cache all files when build project

Tags: laravel, caching, vue.js, laravel-mix, workbox

I use `Vuejs` and I use `workbox-webpack-plugin` in order to make my site offline, I want to cache a folder which contains all my files (3 files) like picture below, but when I build my project(using `Laravel-mix`). The `main.js` (which contains everything of Vue) cannot be cached in `service-woker.js`. I tried some ways to fix that but those didn't work. 
Does anybody face this issue, do you have any solution, many thanks!

->>[image: picture-description]

Comment: Can you provide your full Webpack configuration? It sounds like the Workbox plugin is running too early, before the `main.js` file is generated by Webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Some time ago, a guy on GitHub helped me figure this out.

It's because there's a Workbox config property called `maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes`. By default it is set to 2MB, which means it will only cache files that are smaller than (or equal to) 2MB. Some of my built files are larger than that. I only needed to increase the `maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes` to solve the issue and include those larger files in the generated service worker.

My updated Workbox config looks like this:

```js
plugins: [
  new workboxPlugin({
    globDirectory: DIST_DIR,
    globPatterns: ['js/*.{html,js,css}'],
    maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000, // <-- Added (5 MB)
    swDest: path.join(DIST_DIR, 'sw.js'),
  }),
]
```

Comment: where(the filename and location) do you put maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you dealing it manually? Even though you can cache all static asset using

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);
```

and for dynamic request please use routing with strategy:-

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute('end point url', workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
cacheName: 'cache-name'
}));
```