# js/chunk-vendors.js won't be precached

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a project which involves `pwa`... However, when I successfully integrated `pwa` into the project, the compile process warns me of

```
WARNING  Compiled with 1 warning                                                                                                                  8:10:04 AM

js/chunk-vendors.js is 20 MB, and won't be precached. Configure maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes to change this limit.
```

The complete log is here.

```
➜  site git:(master) ✗ yarn serve
yarn run v1.22.10
$ vue-cli-service serve
 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 WARNING  Compiled with 1 warning                                                                                                                  8:10:04 AM

js/chunk-vendors.js is 20 MB, and won't be precached. Configure maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes to change this limit.

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080 
  - Network: http://10.58.0.212:8080

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run yarn build.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129776/workbox-cannot-cache-all-files-when-build-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46795409/how-to-cache-larger-files-for-development).

Comment: how, then, do I set `maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes`?

Comment: That depends on how you're building your app and where your config is, but there should be something like a Workbox plugin or InjectManifest plugin somewhere that would take the options.